# How to access a form in a directive from the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular directive that contains a form with validation.  I want to have a button in my view that gets disabled when this directive's form is `$pristine`, but the button exists in the view at the level of the controller, so I have no access to the child form inside the directive.

How can I access the form inside the directive from the parent controller without doing some weird hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one fine way to do it. Expose a directive controller, like the form does by exposing the `FormController` object on the current scope. Since your directive creates isolated scope, the code will look like:

```
controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
   $scope.$parent[$attrs.myDirectiveName]=this;   // Exposes the directive controller on the parent scope with name myDirectiveName

   // Now you can define a function that tells state of the form. Or expose the form on the controller
   this.isPristine=function() {
       return $scope.formName.$pristine;
   }
}
```

Once the directive controller is there, you attach the directive to a html element and the controller is available on the current scope.

`<div my-directive='mydir'></div> // create a property $scope.mydir on current scope.`

Now you can check the state using `$scope.mydir.isPristine()`

Comment: That would work, but does it go against how angular wants to be used?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by it. With this approach you are exposing the directive API through a controller, added to the scope. It is similar to how Angular `form` directive does it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add to the button ng-disabled

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vhsmdcn/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="bob">
      <input name="some" type="text" ng-model="pie"/>
      <button ng-disabled="bob.$pristine">Submit</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Like I said, the form exists INSIDE a directive, which means that the scope of its FormController exists within that directive only since it uses an isolated scope